# Are there simple ways to construct shelving under a kitchen worktable?

Tags: kitchens, table, shelf

I have the following worktable in my kitchen:[image]

I'd like to have another "shelf" below the table top. Are there any simple solutions to this problem?

It might be possible to purchase another shelf from the manufacturer, but I think this would be expensive and installing another shelf by "slipping" it on will likely be very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

it is somewhat difficult to answer because I cannot tell what is easy for you.  It depends a lot of what kind of tools you have.

One way I can think of requiring basic tools would be to cut 3 pieces of 2x4 to fit between the legs and attach them to the leg with screws.  They are horizontally placed about 12” below your table top.  Then cut the shelf and have it rest on top of the 3 pieces of wood.  Attach the shelf it support with wood glue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be difficult/complex to try to hang a shelf from those tubular legs. A simpler way would be to size a shelf that fits inside of those legs, supported independently with traditional shelf brackets attached to the wall (this would prohibit easy movement of the table, however).

Comment: It I were to do it, I would use a full size shelf with holes drilled to the size of the legs. I would slide the shelf either up or down the legs and support it by bolting through the legs.